# How to sort/reformat text information in a file?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sort, text-formatting

I have a file (called `customers`) with information that needs to be sorted;
example:

```
qweasd,asdqwd@asd.org,256.62394383
qweasdczasd,asdghjghqwd@assssd.org,256.62394383
qwedddasd,asdasdaqwd@asd.org,256.62394383
qweavvvdsd,asaaadqwd@asccd.org,256.62394383
```

Output of the file must be tab-separated.

```
qweasd         asdqwd@asd.org              256.62394383
qweasdczasd    asdghjghqwd@assssd.org      256.62394383
qwedddasd      asdasdaqwd@asd.org          256.62394383
qweavvvdsd     asaaadqwd@asccd.org         256.62394383
```

I need the command in one line.

Comment: How is the output sorted any differently than the input? If that's your most difficult automation task for the day, please consider accepting my resume for review.

Comment: Is that not just `tr , '\t' < file` you need? What has that to do with _sorting_ or _awk_?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: To be fair, the OP never mentioned awk.  The `/awk` tag was added by the person who submitted the first answer (which features `awk`).

Comment: @G-Man, indeed, that's a bit cheeky. awk is a poor choice here as an answer let alone a tag for the question, I don't understand why that was approved. The whole Q&A is poorly worded and unlikely to be useful to anyone anyway, no need to lose sleep over it.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: As it happens, I voted to reject the edit, but I got outvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use awk commands:

```
# awk -F, '{print $1 "\t" $2 "\t" $3}' customers
```

or :

```
# awk 'BEGIN{FS=","; OFS="\t"} {print $1, $2, $3}' customers
```

or :

```
# awk 'BEGIN{FS=","; OFS="\t"} {print}' customers
```

all of them will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
 awk -F, '{print $1 "\t" $2 "\t" $3}' filename
 awk 'BEGIN{FS=","; OFS="\t"} {print $1, $2, $3}' filename

Answer (score 0):

`sed` is the more simple and efficient tool for this editor grade modification:

```
sed 's-,-ctrlVtab-g' customers
```

You can also very easily achieve the same modification with `ex`, `vi` or `emacs`.